# "Heads up! Could not open project" error message in EV3 software

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming, mac

Whenever we try to edit one of our old projects our EV3 Mindstorms Home software shows us the "Heads up! Could not open project" screen. What should we do?

I am on the Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.3 version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the program file?

Comment: @DavidLechner: Unfortunately we cannot share the program file through here but is there any way that you know that we can share it to you?

Comment: @DavidLechner: We were able to edit the post of with a picture of the code, still unable to share a file though. Hope this helps! Thanks!

Comment: How did you get a screenshot if the file will not open? Could you use a file-sharing app like DropBox/OneDrive/GoogleDrive to share the file?